# turn off cookie_secure in apache for only one virtual host?

Tags: apache, session, session-cookies, virtualhost

I have session.cookie_secure turned on in my php.ini.  This affects every virtual host on my server.  (This is actually my development server, but I prefer to keep the settings as close to my production site as possible.)

But I have one development site on a virtual host on that same Apache server.  I do not want session.cookie_secure on that site.  Is there a way to turn it off just for that site using the virtual host file?

I found this site:
https://geekflare.com/httponly-secure-cookie-apache/

They show that to turn it ON, you do:

```
Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;HttpOnly;Secure
```

Can I unset it via the virtual host?  I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;HttpOnly;Secure=Off
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If PHP runs as an Apache module, you can set that in a `.htaccess` file or in your virtual host configuration:

`php_flag session.cookie_secure Off`

If it runs as CGI/FCGI, it's more complex. I'd recommend switching to PHP-FPM and setup a specific pool for that virtual host. See https://serversforhackers.com/video/php-fpm-multiple-resource-pools or https://www.linode.com/docs/web-servers/apache/running-fastcgi-php-fpm-on-debian-7-with-apache for more details (you may have to adapt this to the Linux distribution you use).